# download file from ftp server using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to download csv files from ftp server but I receive these error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ftplib


ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.00', 'bingo', 'word')
files = ftp.dir('/')
ftp.cwd("/")
filematch = '*.csv'
target_dir = '/home/toor/ringolist'
import os

for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write))

errors:


sudo ./ftp_ringo.py
: not found.py: 1: ./ftp_ringo.py:
: not found.py: 3: ./ftp_ringo.py:
./ftp_ringo.py: 4: ./ftp_ringo.py: import: not found
: not found.py: 5: ./ftp_ringo.py:
./ftp_ringo.py: 6: ./ftp_ringo.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Looks like your python script is executed as a shell script. Try if `sudo python ...` works. If so: Is the `#!` really the first thing in the script? Maybe your editor is writing an [Unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the front of the file. Also: Is the indentation correct as shown in the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the problem with the code, the problem's in the way you're trying to call it. Try `sudo python code.py` or do `which python` and use the result string instead of `/usr/bin/python` in your script.

Comment: @pretyv5, then I'll have to vote to close the question as the problem you were having was because of a typo. You'd better restore the original question as it may be confusing for other people to find the question with an answer that doesn't now answer this question because it was re-edited.

Comment: Thanks ForceBru how can i run this script as cron job.

Comment: @pretyv5, no idea, unfortunately... I'm not so familiar with cron

Answer (score 1):

This is my updated it works fine in downloading the file :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.00', 'bingo', 'word')
files = ftp.dir('/')
ftp.cwd("/")
filematch = '*.csv'
target_dir = '/home/toor/ringolist'
import os

for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)


        # deletes the files from the FTP after transfer
            ftp.delete(os.path.basename(filename))
```